# How to output text from a C# library to the powershell console?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

In powershell, I load a custom dll that I wrote in C# with

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll)
```

What C# code can I use to output text into the powershell console when calling a function from my library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Console.WriteLine(...)` works perfectly lol

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static class and output method in your C# code that returns the string output. Then call it from powershell like so:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll)    
$result = [Your.Complete.Namespace.YourStaticClass]::YourStaticMethod()    
Write-Output $result
```